# Running Android unit tests with Spock framework

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, spock

I am using:

- Android Studio 2.1.3
- Gradle 2.14.1 (I tried with 2.14 also)
- OpenJDK version "1.8.0_91"

I want to write some Unit tests with [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org) and [Spock](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.1-rc-2/index.html) for sample Android application.

I have already read about [RoboSpock](http://robospock.org/).

When I am trying to run simple test:

```
package a.b.regex

class TestSum extends spock.lang.Specification {

    def "test adding some numbers"() {
        when:
        def a = 5 + 4

        then:
        a == 9
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test in Android Studio I have an error:

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "a.b.regex.TestSum"Empty test suite.
```

Configurations that I used:

1)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'
// ...
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.robospock:robospock:1.0.0'
}
```

2)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'
dependencies {
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"
    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.6:grooid'
}
```

From the console no tests are run at all.
With testing Java applications I have no problem.

Here is the project code where I want to use Spock: [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Abrasha/Streets-Translator)

**Thankfully to [Pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214788/5091346) I found the answer.**

You should use the following configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // or mavenCentral, etc.
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7:grooid'
testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't compile, as you have an assignment instead of a comparison in the `then:` block.

Comment: Yes, but I wrote it as sample for SOF. It is not the source of problem.
But I'll fix it anyway.

Comment: @AndriiAbramov please post full reproducer e.g. on GitHub. The above works for me fine

Comment: @MichalKordas ok, will be done soon

Comment: @MichalKordas I have provided a link to GitHub repository in the bottom of question.

Comment: In your tags I would add ```gradle``` in preference to ```unit-testing``` since it is possible that that is where your problem lies, and since the ```spock``` tag covers ```unit-testing``` interest pretty well already.

Comment: @BalRog thanks
As I said in the question, from console (`./gradlew clean test`) does not work also.
But anyway, I will check it later

Comment: @BalRog done. Yeah, more than 1 year after, but anyway :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)
This should work great other than you are using an outdated version of the groovy android plugin. The current version is 1.0.0. The error you are seeing is that you included your tests in androidTest source folder, when they should be included in the test source folder.

2)
 You do not want groovy-all, and want to exclude that from the spock transitive dependencies as well.

This would look similar to

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7:grooid'
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
      exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
      exclude group: 'junit'
    }
  }
```

Same as the problem with #1 you probably have the source under androidTest folder instead of the test folder.

The androidTest folder is for test that will run on the device, and the test folder if for tests that will run on your machines JVM.

Comment: Yeah!
It works.

As you can see in GitHub repository (I have included the link in the answer) case #1 is not suitable for me (all tests are in the right folder).

But playing around with versions and dependencies solved my problem.
I will post in answer what configurations I used.

Answer (score 3):

If you reached here trying to configure for gradle 6.6 this will help you:

I stepped multiple times into this while trying to configure Spock in android having gradle 6.6, there has been multiple changes in gradle, so they made this plugin deprecated `'groovyx.android'`: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin

`Deprecated: This plugin has been deprecated in favor of Kotlin which has the full support of JetBrains and Google. The changes that go into each Android Plugin Version make it really hard for this plugin to keep up. As of Gradle 6.0 this plugin does not work.`

Found out that gradle have a separate plugin for groovy support:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.codehaus.groovy.android

This is the configuration for gradle 6.6 using groovy DSL for gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

And then in the app configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "org.codehaus.groovy.android"


def groovyVersion = "3.0.5"
def spockVersion = "2.0-M3-groovy-3.0"
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    testImplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:${groovyVersion}")
    testImplementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyVersion}")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:${spockVersion}")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-spring:${spockVersion}")


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been struggling for hours trying to get this right.

Comment: I gave up on this sometime ago, and was seriously considering migrating my project's tests from Spock to JUnit so I can move to a newer version of Gradle.  This helped so much - now I don't have to do that!

Comment: I'm happy for that, I spent some time trying to make this work and I ended up not using it, but I love spock and I really hate how hard it was to find a good documentation on how to use spock with the new gradle version.